# Specify data type with column alias in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Imagine I have the following SELECT statement in a view (SQL Server 2008):

```
SELECT (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN HISTORY.OUTOFSERV = 'Y' OR HISTORY.OUTOFSERV = 'y' THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END) AS OOS 
  FROM HISTORY
```

The column OOS ends up being of type int, but I'd like it to be of type bit. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to explicitly define the data type:

```
SELECT CAST (CASE 
               WHEN LOWER(h.outofserv) = 'y' THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END AS BIT) AS OOS 
 FROM HISTORY h
```

Answer (score 4):

you should just use `CAST(1 as bit)` and `CAST(0 as bit)` instead of 1 and 0:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN HISTORY.OUTOFSERV = 'Y' OR HISTORY.OUTOFSERV = 'y'
             THEN CAST(1 AS bit) 
             ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) 
        END) AS OOS 
FROM HISTORY
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to get the desired BIT datatype output, and with a little cleaner code using:

- upper()
- cast()

  SELECT CAST(CASE
                 WHEN UPPER(History.OutofServ) = 'Y' THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END AS BIT) AS OOS 
  FROM History

I hope that helps.